# Scraping pagination via "page=" midway in url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this webpage, and all 900+ pages that follow: https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&page=1&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&partial=True

It's important that the scraper does not target the pagination link, but rather iterates through the "page=" number in the url. This is because the data present is loaded dynamically in the original webpage, which the pagination links point back to.

I've tried writing something that loops through the page numbers in the url, via the "last" class of the pagination ul, to find the final page, but I am not sure how to target the specific part of the url, whilst keeping the search query the same for each result

```
r = requests.get(url_pagination)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

page_url = "https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&page={}" + "&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&partial=True"
last_page = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find('li', class_='last').a['href'].split('=')[1]
dept_page_url = [page_url.format(i) for i in range(1, int(last_page)+1)]

print(dept_page_url)
```

I would ideally like to scrape just the name from class "secondaryTitle", and the 2nd unnamed div that contains the date, per row.

I keep getting an error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2019-07-11&searchTerm'

Comment: I would recommend parsing the URLs with a URL parser and extracting the query string field page and not with split. This is what Python has urllib for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this script, but beware, it goes from page `1` all the way to last page `966`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

next_page_url = 'https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&page=1&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&partial=True'

# this goes to page '966'
while True:
    print('Scrapping {} ...'.format(next_page_url))
    r = requests.get(next_page_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for secondary_title, date in zip(soup.select('.secondaryTitle'), soup.select('.secondaryTitle + *')):
        print('{: >20} - {}'.format(date.get_text(strip=True), secondary_title.get_text(strip=True)))

    next_link = soup.select_one('a:has(span:contains(Next))')
    if next_link:
        next_page_url = 'https://hansard.parliament.uk' + next_link['href'] + '&partial=True'
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
Scrapping https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&page=1&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&partial=True ...
     17 January 2007 - Ian Pearson
    21 December 2017 - Baroness Vere of Norbiton
          2 May 2019 - Lord Parekh
     4 February 2013 - Baroness Hanham
    21 December 2017 - Baroness Walmsley
     9 February 2010 - Colin Challen
     6 February 2002 - Baroness Farrington of Ribbleton
       24 April 2007 - Barry Gardiner
     17 January 2007 - Rob Marris
        7 March 2002 - The Parliamentary Under-Secretary of State, Department for Environment, Food and Rural Affairs (Lord Whitty)
     27 October 1999 - Mr. Tom Brake  (Carshalton and Wallington)
     9 February 2004 - Baroness Miller of Chilthorne Domer
        7 March 2002 - The Secretary of State for Environment, Food and Rural Affairs (Margaret Beckett)
    27 February 2007 - 
      8 October 2008 - Baroness Andrews
       24 March 2011 - Lord Henley
    21 December 2017 - Lord Krebs
    21 December 2017 - Baroness Young of Old Scone
        16 June 2009 - Mark Lazarowicz
        14 July 2006 - Lord Rooker
Scrapping https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&page=2&partial=True ...
     12 October 2006 - Lord Barker of Battle
     29 January 2009 - Lord Giddens


... and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you are using the wrong number from your split. You want -1. Observe:

```
last_page = soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find('li', class_='last').a['href']
print(last_page)
print(last_page.split('=')[1])
print(last_page.split('=')[-1])
```

Gives:

```
/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&page=966
```

when split and use 1

```
2019-07-11&searchTerm
```

versus  -1

```
966
```

To get the info from each page you want I would do pretty much what the other answer does in terms of css selectors and zipping. Some other looping constructs below and use of Session for efficiency given number of requests.

---

You could make an initial request and extract the number of pages then loop for those. Use Session object for efficiency of connection re-use.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def make_soup(s, page):
    page_url = "https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&page={}&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&partial=True"
    r = s.get(page_url.format(page))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = make_soup(s, 1)
    pages = int(soup.select_one('.last a')['href'].split('page=')[1])
    for page in range(2, pages + 1):
        soup = make_soup(s, page)
        #do something with soup
```

---

You could loop until class `last` ceases to appear

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

present = True
page = 1
#results = {}

def make_soup(s, page):
    page_url = "https://hansard.parliament.uk/search/Contributions?endDate=2019-07-11&page={}&searchTerm=%22climate+change%22&startDate=1800-01-01&partial=True"
    r = s.get(page_url.format(page))
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup

with requests.Session() as s:
    while present:
        soup = make_soup(s, page)
        present = len(soup.select('.last')) > 0
        #results[page] = soup.select_one('.pagination-total').text
        #extract info
        page+=1
```